# How do I add parameters to my queries when using clr/c++ for multiple variables

Tags: c++-cli, sqlclr

I want to be able to add parameters to my queries to make my statements less vunerable to sql injections

My code (Key parts are surrounded by ** as I cannot make code bold)

```
        OleDbConnection^ existingSqlConnection = nullptr;
        existingSqlConnection = gcnew OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
            "Data Source =" + "myDatabaseV3.accdb");
        **String^ sqlText = "SELECT * FROM @tableName WHERE @fieldName = @fieldEntityName";
        OleDbCommand^ dbCommand = gcnew OleDbCommand(sqlText, existingSqlConnection);
        OleDbParameterCollection^ paramCollection = dbCommand->Parameters;
        dbCommand->Parameters->Add(gcnew OleDbParameter("@tableName", tableName->ToString()));
        dbCommand->Parameters->AddWithValue("@fieldName", field);**
        dbCommand->Parameters->AddWithValue("@fieldEntityName", fieldEntity);
        **Console::WriteLine(dbCommand->CommandText);
        Console::WriteLine(paramCollection->Count);** 
        existingSqlConnection->Open();
        OleDbDataReader^ reader = dbCommand->ExecuteReader(System::Data::CommandBehavior::CloseConnection);

        return reader;
```

The output for this is

SELECT * FROM @tableName WHERE @fieldName = @fieldEntityName

3

Which clearly shows that there are 3 parameters but they are not being added to my query which is the problem I want to be solved

Comment: How do you know they aren't being added to your query?

Comment: @user253751 Because the output I get in my console::writeline outputs my query and it isn't showing my parameters

Comment: Why do you expect it to show the parameters? When you ask for the command you get the command; when you ask for the parameters you get the parameters (you can see this because the second line says 3, and if you printed the parameter values you'd probably get those too)

Answer (score 0):

This is not how parameters work. They are not replacement values for text templates. Parameters are a mechanism to pass in a value to the variable in the query, just like passing a parameter to a stored procedure will pass that value in to be used as a variable in the query.

Along these lines, parameters can only be used where variables can be used in queries. And, variables cannot be used for object names, which is why people resort to using SQL Injection when the table and/or column name(s) need to change. In your example code:

- `@tableName` could never be a variable in a query, hence it cannot be a parameter
- `@fieldName` could never be a variable in a query, hence it cannot be a parameter
- `@fieldEntityName` if it is supposed to be a value and not a column name, can be a parameter, in which case it will remain as `@fieldEntityName` in the query, and it will have a value of `fieldEntity`.

Please see the second option of [my answer on your related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59971367/577765) for how to prevent SQL Injection (short answer: sanitize inputs).

Also, using `AddWithValue()` is a bad practice. Create the parameter with the intended max size, then give that a value, and finally add it to the parameters collection. You do *not* want it to auto-detect the max size for the parameter as it will use the first value it gets, and any subsequent value that is longer will be silently truncated.

Comment: I am very confused by this. I cannot use my parameters because they cannot be variables. I don't understand what this means. I just want to know what I should do to make my code work. Maybe a visual representation / example of this would be better suited. I want it so that the @... are replaced by my variables (which have been passed as a parameter into this function)

Comment: @L.A Parameters here are exactly the same as parameters to stored procedures. You cannot use a parameter of a stored procedure to take the place of a column name, table name, or anything like that. They are variables and can only be used in calculations, concatenations, tests, comparisons, etc. So, if you have `SELECT * FROM dbo.TableName WHERE fieldName = @fieldEntityName;` then `@fieldEntityName` is a valid use as it takes the place of a literal (string, number, etc). But nowhere in T-SQL can you do `SELECT * FROM @TableName;` Again, please see option 2 in my answer on your initial question.